# django digitalocean deploy cannot serve static files

Tags: django, digital-ocean

I try to deploy my app on digitalocean, when i configure the ngnix server, everything works except all the css and js file are not being served.
I have done collectstatic, and my /etc/nginx/sites-available looks like this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my ip;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
        root /home/djangodeploy/portfolio-blog;
    }

     location /media/ {
        root /home/djangodeploy/portfolio-blog;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/djangodeploy/portfolio-blog/mysite.sock;
    }
}
```

and my file structure looks like this

[image]

settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite/static') ]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: Let's start from your settings file. Could you show your settings related to media/static?

Comment: STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite/static')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

Comment: I'm not familiar with DO's Django deployment. In our case, we point nginx directly to the actual `static` and `media` folders. You seem to only point to the parent folder? And we are using `alias <path>` and not `root <path>` in the nginx config.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try:

```
    location /static/ {
        root /home/djangodeploy/portfolio-blog/static;
    }

     location /media/ {
        root /home/djangodeploy/portfolio-blog/media;
    }
```